# Hide black bar under Samsung keyboard when user types on EditText

Tags: java, android

How to hide the keyboard black bar on Samsung smartphones when user types in edit text on android. I tried it with `android:inputType="textNoSuggestions|textVisiblePassword"`, but it only hides the suggestions.

[This black bar.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xVgxd.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't.  That's part of the samsung keyboard.  The keyboard itself gets to decide whether to show it or not.  At best you can try to find an input type that gives it a hint to do so, but that may screw up other keyboards, and may not work on other versions of they keyboard.